# How to calculate $ \int_0^{\frac{ \pi }{2}} \frac{\sin^{1395}x}{\sin^{1395}x + \cos^{1395}x}\ dx $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Solve the following integrals:

$$ \int_0^{\frac{ \pi }{2}} \frac{\sin^{1395}x}{\sin^{1395}x + \cos^{1395}x}\ dx $$

And it does not follow a specific pattern.

Comment: I have to ask, where did this question come from?

Comment: The frequency of questions based on this trick seems to be increasing...

Answer (score 14):

Recall this useful formula: $$\int_a^b f(x)\ \mathrm dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\ \mathrm dx$$

Let the required value of the integral be $I$. Now, we have: $$ I=\int_0^{\frac{ \pi }{2}} \frac{\sin^{1395}x}{\sin^{1395}x + \cos^{1395}x}\ \mathrm dx = \int_0^{\frac{ \pi }{2}} \frac{\sin^{1395}(\frac\pi2-x)}{\sin^{1395}(\frac\pi2-x) + \cos^{1395}(\frac\pi2-x)}\ \mathrm dx$$

Simplifying: $$I=\int_0^{\frac{ \pi }{2}} \frac{\cos^{1395}x}{\sin^{1395}x + \cos^{1395}x}\ \mathrm dx$$

Adding the two equations: $$2I=\int_0^{\frac{ \pi }{2}} \frac{\sin^{1395}x+\cos^{1395}x}{\sin^{1395}x + \cos^{1395}x}\ \mathrm dx=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\mathrm dx=\frac\pi2$$

Therefore: $$I=\frac\pi4$$

Comment: Wow, brilliant!

Comment: This is beautiful. Well done.

Comment: An "oldie" but a "goodie."